# Nuxt app hosting on firebase function URL end with "/" before queries

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I am building a Nuxt app hosting on firebase function. When I see the URLs on local, they look fine, however, on firebase they end with "/" before queries. Am I missing any settings?

example:

`https://xxxxx.firebaseapp.com/select-prefecture/?type=blocks`

`http://localhost:4000/select-prefecture?type=blocks`

[production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhqAH.png)

[local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVRh7.png)

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "xxxxxx",
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The url with "/" on firebase you copied from firebase console? Did you tried to use it without the "/" ?

Comment: When I remove "/" and press enter, it automatically redirects to the same url with "/".

Comment: Isnt behind in function some sort of redirect happening? Some router from nuxt etc.